# difference between django-allauth process='connect/login'

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

here in the [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#social-account-tags) there is an optional parameter `process` which can take either **login** or **connect**.

using `process='login'` it works properly and **creates** new user if there isn't any, while `process='connect'` does **nothing**.(I was expecting it to login ***just if there is a user*** ..). but i have no idea on, how that works..

I have a `loginForm` and `SignUpForm` where both have the social *login/signup* option, and I don't want it to create account when it's clicked on social icon on `LoginForm`.

how can i perform this. (sorry if messed up things..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the whether or not the user wants to create a whole new account through the social account or simply add a new social account to an existing account, with *process="login"* pertaining to the former and *process="connect"* the latter.

### Example Scenarios:

For example, a new user wants to sign up using google, and then proceed creating a new account: **process="login"**. The default "login.html" template in django-allauth does exactly this so that new users can immediately sign-up/log-in with a social account.

The other situation is when an existing user decides they also want to be able to login with "Google" or "Microsoft" then **process="connect"** . Typically this functionality to connect a new social account is found in the settings page for a logged in account.